# Why does scaling of one predictor influence the coefficient estimates of other predictors in ridge regression?

Tags: regularization, standardization, ridge-regression

In [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/) it is written

> The standard least squares coefficient estimates discussed in Chapter 3
> are scale equivariant: multiplying $X_j$ by a constant $c$ simply leads to a
> scaling of the least squares coefficient estimates by a factor of $1/c$. In other
> words, regardless of how the $j$th predictor is scaled, $X_j\hat{β}_j$ will remain the
> same. In contrast, the ridge regression coefficient estimates can change substantially when multiplying a given predictor by a constant. For instance,
> consider the income variable, which is measured in dollars. One could reasonably have measured income in thousands of dollars, which would result
> in a reduction in the observed values of income by a factor of 1,000. Now due
> to the sum of squared coefficients term in the ridge regression formulation
> (6.5), such a change in scale will not simply cause the ridge regression coefficient estimate for income to change by a factor of 1,000. In other words,
> $X_j\hat{\beta}_{j, \lambda}^R$ will depend not only on the value of λ, but also on the scaling of the $j$th predictor. In fact, the value of $X_j\hat{\beta}_{j, \lambda}^R$ may even ***depend on the scaling of the other predictors***! (Emphasis mine). Therefore, it is best to apply ridge regression after standardizing the predictors ...

> $\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(y_i - \beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_jx_{ij}\bigg)^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j^2 = RSS + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j^2,$ (6.5)

It does make sense to me that an estimated coefficient for a predictor will obtain a different value, because of the L2 penalty. A predictor scaled for example by $\frac{1}{100}$ would have a coefficient estimate larger by a factor of $100$ in ordinary least squares and that larger coefficient estimate would be penalized in ridge, hence the need for scaling all predictors.

My question is - How can the magnitude of one predictor affect coefficient estimates of other predictors?

I can see that a coefficient estimate with a large value will increase the penalty term and other coefficient estimates can be penalized for that as well, but I don't feel like I have the full picture.

Also, again in ISLR it is written

> While the ridge coefficient estimates tend to decrease in aggregate as λ increases, individual coefficients, such as rating and income, may occasionally increase as λ increases.
> [image]

Why? What is the mechanizm, by which the scale and estimated coefficient of one predictor can have a direct influence on coefficient estimates of other predictors?

Comment: Look in esl for solutions for orthogonal data.(p 66). No effect on other variables. So now consider the case of perfectly correlated variables